# How do I play a run of keys or a certain pattern of ascending or descending notes, fast?

Tags: piano

Say I have to play from C to C by pressing every key,not a glissando.
How do I practice doing this?
I think I've seen sheets where there are parts that go from C to B(of the other octave).
If they were longer notes I think I could manage to adjust my hand in time.
But how do I play this properly when it's rather short notes.
8ths or 16ths.Actually I'd have problems with 4ths aswell if the song is fast.

Sorry if I'm explaining this badly.I don't have much knowledge of music.
Here's an image of something that I can find thats in a way related.

[image: https://puu.sh/le7sW/46a3d6b13f.png]

Here's one image.
But I would also like to know how to play when there aren't any notes that play twice in row,like that C C or when all the keys are one after another 
like CDEFGABCDEFGAB quickly.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get it.  CDEFGABCDEFGAB sounds like a scale.  Your sample shows sort of an arpeggio.  I don't see a repeated C anywhere.

Comment: @As I think I've said about 100 times before on similar questions, you *must start and practice slow*. Very, obnoxiously slow. So slow that you can play it without making a mistake. Keep a practice journal. Every day you practice, write down your metronome speed. Try to improve by 1 click every session. Repeat this process until you can play comfortably beyond your target speed. The more you do this, over time, the less you will need to do it. To play fast, you must play slow.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're asking how to play a chromatic scale rapidly. With R.H., every black key is played using the middle finger. B and E are with thumb, C and F with the index finger. this is the usual and accepted way to play every note/key on piano with R.H. quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give: "**CDEFGABCDEFGAB**" simply practicing scales will make something like this very very simple.

When you say repeating a note I assume you mean the same type of scalar phrase but with one pitch repeated in the pattern, for example: "**CDEFGGAB**" where the **G** is repeated. This could prove to be much more difficult depending on the context it is in, however practicing basic scales will still be extremely important.

When you are repeating one of the pitches immediately after, you have to determine if you can tap your finger quickly enough to avoid having to change fingerings.

If this is not possible, simply analyse the entire phrase from top to bottom and work out which fingering would be the best for that given situation.

For example, the "**CDEFGGAB**" example I mentioned before would go something like this:

**C(2)  D(1)  E(2)  F(3)  G(4)  G(1)  A(2)  B(3)**

Where the thumb repeats the **G**.

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for. Hope I can help!